# Nginx rewirte ruel file path

Tags: nginx

I have setup a nginx on my server and now i need to redirect the no example to www.example.com so i request everyone why i am not getting the desired result as i have done everything so  please let me know If i am doing wrong . I have added this code nginx.conf file

```
server {
        #listen 80 is default
        server_name www.example.com;
        return 301 $scheme://example.com$request_uri;
    }

    server {
        #listen 80 is default
        server_name example.com;
        ## here goes the rest of your conf...
    }
```

I have added this code the nginx.conf file but its not working the way i want . I want non www redirect to www , so i want to know if am doing anything wrong please let me know

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question, you require `example.com` to redirect to `www.example.com`. So basically, you have your `server` containers the wrong way around. Try this:

```
  server {
    server_name example.com;
    return 301 $scheme://www.example.com$request_uri;
  }
  server {
    server_name www.example.com;
    ## here goes the rest of your conf...
  }
```